# Can Nystul's Magic Aura mask a creature created by a Protean Scribe?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

I play a [Protean Scribe (from *Mythical Classes* by LPJ Design)](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/m/product/200561) and it has word powers. You can write a story so eloquent that you can bring the very creatures and objects of your story into existence.

In either case, the storied creature or object is obviously magical, radiating dim light in a 5 ft radius. An object or creature remains until it is reduced to 0 hit points, you choose to erase the story, or until you take a short or long rest.

If I cast *Nystul's magic aura*, can I prevent the creature radiating dim light in a 5-foot radius? Does this spell mask this effect?

Comment: @Aspedies Note: To respond to other users and answers, use comments, starting with @ and the user you're responding to (example: @Aspedies). Don't post comments as new answers.

Answer (score 11):

## No, it wouldn't mask it

The [*magic aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura) spell's masking effect applies only to spells and magical effects, and at that only those that detect creatures types.  It does not change the way the creature actually appears in general.

> You change the way the target appears to **spells and magical effects** that detect creature types...

Regular vision is not a magical effect nor a spell.

Comment: You may want to reference a similar situation in the core game that could occur from something like the Minor Conjuration feature of the conjuration wizard: "you can use your action to conjure up an inanimate object... The object is visibly magical, radiating dim light out to 5 feet.